# How to track "Hide keyboard" button on iPad in searchBar?

Tags: ios, swift

I have searchBar and tableView. I have a bug, when user clicks on "hide keyboard". I have tried to user Notification Center for hiding keyboard. But it also works for "cancel" button. Maybe there is a way to exclude determining "cancel button"?

Answer (score 0):

On hide keyboard button click listener you can use two from the below options

1) `self.view.endEditing(true)`

> This will notify your current active view to stop editing which will
>   automatically hides the keyboard

2) `yourTextField.resignFirstResponder`

> This will stop focusing your current editing textView which will
>   automatically hide the keyboard.

As you will write this code specific to your **Hide keyboard** button it won't apply the same solution to your **Cancel button**.

Comment: How to create listener for "hide keyboard" button?

Comment: I am assuming you have already implemented hide keyboard listener bcz that's how you have written in the question if not then share me the code so that i can help you further.